# Losing frames when clipping videos with ffmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I seem to be losing frames when I clip videos up with ffmpeg.

Here are the steps I take:

[Get the Frame number to cut on] -> [turn the frame number into hh:mm:ss.ms format] -> [Run ffmpeg process]

Here is the code:

```
import subprocess

def frames_to_timecode(frame,frameRate):
    '''
    Convert frame into a timecode HH:MM:SS.MS
    frame = The frame to convert into a time code
    frameRate = the frame rate of the video
    '''
    #convert frames into seconds
    seconds = frame / frameRate

    #generate the time code
    timeCode = '{h:02d}:{m:02d}:{s:02f}'.format(
    h=int(seconds/3600),
    m=int(seconds/60%60),
    s=seconds%60)

    return timeCode

frameRate = 24.0

inputVideo = r"C:\Users\aquamen\Videos\vlc-record-2018-10-23-17h11m11s-SEQ-0200_animatic_v4_20180827_short.mp4"
outputVideo = r"C:\Users\aquamen\Videos\ffmpeg_test_clip001.mp4"
ffmpeg = r"C:\ffmpeg\ffmpeg-20181028-e95987f-win64-static\bin\ffmpeg.exe" 

endFrame = frames_to_timecode(29,frameRate)
startFrame = frames_to_timecode(10,frameRate)

subprocess.call([ffmpeg,'-i',inputVideo,'-ss',startFrame,'-to',endFrame,outputVideo])
```

Here is a image of the original video and the clipped video with the time codes showing a frame was lost in process. The time code should show 00:01:18:10 instead its 00:01:18:11.

[image: Original Video that clip was taken from]

[image: Clipped Video that's missing the frame]

Comment: If the string values returned by your `frames_to_timecode()` function are correct, it doesn't sound like a Python issue. Would probably be best if you contacted the developers of `ffmpeg`...

Comment: Timestamps need not be smooth i.e. frame X may not be at time `X/rate`. Share the source if you can.

Comment: @Gyan I sadly can not share the source files do to there nature for work. Do you mean that dividing your frame by your frame rate is not a guarantee frame in ms?

Comment: @martineau I have shared this question with the mailing list of ffmpeg to see if I can get a answer as well.

Comment: Mark C: If doing that helps solve the problem, please post the solution here (which you can even accept as the answer afterwards). Doing so could be helpful to others with a similar issue.

Comment: @martineau I have posted the answer below please up vote for people in the future

Comment: @Gyan I have posted the answer below please up vote for people in the future

Answer (score 4):

So a friend of mine figured this out. So if you divide the frame by the fps (Frame/fps) you get the point of when that frame needs to be cut with the -ss but the problem is by default python rounds the 12 decimal place. So you need to NOT round the number and give ffmpeg only up to 3 decimal places.

So here is my revised code for any one running into this problem. If you want to cut a video on the Frame number use this:

```
import subprocess


def frame_to_seconds(frame,frameRate):
    '''
    This will turn the frame into seconds.miliseconds
    so you can cut on frames in ffmpeg
    frame = The frame to convert into seconds
    frameRate = the frame rate of the video
    '''
    frameRate = float(frameRate)
    seconds = frame / frameRate
    result = str(seconds - seconds % 0.001)

    return result

inputVideo = "yourVideo.mp4"

outputVideo = "clipedVideo.mp4"
ffmpeg = r"C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe" 

frameRate = 24

subprocess.call([ffmpeg,
                 '-i',inputVideo,
                 '-ss',frame_to_seconds(10,frameRate),
                 '-to',frame_to_seconds(20,frameRate),
                 outputVideo])
```